# Insert a row to beginning or ending of a 2D array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array like this:

```
array a: (m)x(n) 
1 2 3 4 5 6
2 3 4 5 6 7
3 4 5 6 7 8
4 5 6 7 8 9
```

and I want to insert this row to the beginning of the array:

```
row b: (1)x(n) 
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

to get array like this:

```
array c:  (m+1)x(n)
0 1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 6
2 3 4 5 6 7
3 4 5 6 7 8
4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I tried this way:

- Create an empty array c:(m+1)x(n)
- Assign row b to first row of array c.
- Assign other rows of array a to array c.

It do well but I realize that it's to long.
Can I do it shorter? And how?

Comment: Provide some code please!

Comment: I managed the problem already:
add to first row: array_unshift($array,$first_row);
add to last row: array_push($array,$last_row);

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArray = (0,1,2,3,4,5);
array_unshift($array, $newArray);
```